# column show/hide in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid columnChooser, like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list_records").jqGrid({
        url: "getGridData.php",
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["User Id", "User Name","Password"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "userId",align:"right"},
            { name: "userName"},
            { name: "password"},

        ],
        pager: "#perpage",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10,20],
        sortname: "userId",
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: "test"
    }); 
    $("#list_records").jqGrid('columnChooser');
    $("#list_records").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#perpage', {
caption: "showcolumns",
buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
title: "Choose columns",
onClickButton: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser');
    $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + " ul.selected")
        .bind("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {
            alert('column "' + ui.item.text() + '" is choosed');
        });
    $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + " ul.available a.action")
        .click(function () {
            alert('column "' + $(this).parent().text() + '" is choosed');
        });

   }
 });    
 });
 </script>
```

but i want my grid  look like as 
  http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser8.htm

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you should remove `$("#list_records").jqGrid('columnChooser');` call before `navButtonAdd`
2. `navButtonAdd` can be used to add custom button to navigator bar, but it didn't work if no navigator bar exist in the grid. So you have to include call of `navGrid` before calling of `navButtonAdd`. For example, `$("#list_records").jqGrid('navGrid', '#perpage', {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});`

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your reply, iam new to this jqgrid, could you please provide the code of this link: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser8.htm

Comment: Thank you so much [Oleg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)  it is working

Comment: @Sravya: You are welcome! To see the code of demo you can just to open context menu (click right mouse button) and choose "View page source" (or "View source" depend on web browser which you use).

Comment: Hi [Oleg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) thanks again, could you help me for one more time, iam adding ui.multiselect.js and ui.multiselect.css, but iam not getting that view for dialog box which you got in this link http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5__.htm when iam clicking on show columns

Comment: @Sravya: Verify that you included `jquery-ui.min.js` between `ui.multiselect.js` and `jquery.min.js`. Compare the list and the order of included JS and CSS files on your page.

Comment: Hi Oleg, could you help me that how to display select columns option outside of the grid